# Conditional probability with binomial distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have a sequence of n coin tosses with probability of heads as p for each toss. Then the probability of k heads is defined by the binomial probability Pr(Y = k) = nCk p^k (1-p)^(n-k). I am trying to compute the conditional probability for a specific sequence given the number of heads. Example: if we toss a coin 3 times and we are given that there is 2 heads, what is the probability that it was in the first and second toss? I.e, Pr(X = HHT | Y=2). I tried to compute this as 1/3C2 since there are 3C2 possible ways of getting 2 heads and the sequence is one of them. But it is not a probability distribution since it adds up to 2 instead of 1. Can someone help with what I am missing?

Comment: "But it is not a probability distribution since it adds up to 2 instead of 1."—Can you show your work here, so we can see what's missing? Doing this in my head, I get 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1.

Comment: I was adding up the probability for all possible Ys I.e, 1/3C0 + 1/3C1 + 1/3C2 + 1/3C3 which adds up to 2 as a limiting value as the number of coin tosses increase

Comment: Ah! But you've said, "given that there is 2 heads". You don't sum over conditions. You sum over events _conditioned on that condition_. p(HHT | Y=2) + p(HTH | Y=2) + p(THH | Y=2). (Think about it: in notation, what would be the terms you're adding up? Contrast it with mine.)